# JNI how to bridge some of the complex object and callbacks

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk

My android project requires some C++/C libraries,and I've got a library (.so) and some headers(.h). and I have reference to some simple demo, using JNI bridge some simple functions, but This lib is complicated for me. How bridging these complex objects and callback.

1. Created a android project
2. Copy xxx.so into lib/armeabi, copy all .h files to jni folder.
3. I want use JNI bridging these c ++ function, I konw I need creat a MStack.h and MStack.cpp to implement these functions, But these headers class makes me very confused，I'm not familiar with C++

some .h like this :

```
class SIPSTACK_API ISipStack : public Component::IUnknown
{
public:

class IFactory : public Component::IFactoryUnknown
{
public:

    virtual ISipStack* create() = 0;


    static const char* iid() {return "SipStack";}
};  
public:
virtual ~ISipStack(void){}

///@brief 
///\param [in] config 
///\note 
virtual bool setConfig(SipConfigInfo& config)
    COMPONENT_UNIMPLEMENTED_OPERATION


///\param [in] handler 
///\note  
virtual bool start(void)
    COMPONENT_UNIMPLEMENTED_OPERATION

///@brief 
enum
{
    inviteHandler = 0,   
    actRegHandler,       
    pasRegHandler,       
    outCallMsgHandler,  
    subscribeHandler,    
    proxyHandler        
};

/// @brief 
///\param[in] type inviteHandler、registerHandler    
///\param[in] handler  
///\note  
virtual bool attachHandler(int type, Component::IUnknown* handler)
    COMPONENT_UNIMPLEMENTED_OPERATION
```

.....

How can I put these into the corresponding .h and implemented in the cpp. Thanks!